# vagrant up stuck on mount nfs

Tags: macos, vagrant, nfs

When I attempt to initiate 'vagrant up' the script executes as normal until it gets to the last line, where NFS shared drives are mounted.

I have tried deleting the exports file in /etc/ followed by a nfsd restart and vagrant destroy / vagrant up but to no avail.

After some considerable amount of time the console outputs the following [certain details redacted]:

```
*==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...*

   *The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!*

*mount -o 'nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime' XXX.XXX.XX.X:'/Users/dhatton/Google Drive/moodle-doodle/site' /var/www/site*

*Stdout from the command:*

*Stderr from the command:*

*mount.nfs: Connection timed out*
```

***UPDATE***

The above problem was encountered when using a VPN into the office network. Upon logging in on-site without the VPN, everything works again.

Answer (score 4):

For macOS **Monterey 12.1** with virtualBox 6.1.30 and vagrant Vagrant 2.2.19/18:

1. create vbox folder in /etc
2. create a file inside /etc/vbox named networks.conf
3. add the following inside networks.conf

   `* 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0`

**Note**: if you get the ip address range error, add your IP here too.

Comment: Also works for Vagrant 2.2.16

Comment: Explain why we should do this.

Comment: This worked, and un-stuck mac os x, even under a full VPN under Big Sur 11.2.3

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. I searched a lot, and tried following solutions:

1. Check `/etc/exports` and `/etc/hosts` files, if there are invalid entries in file, remove them.
2. Check your firewall is not blocking access
3. Restart NFS system
4. install `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest` plugin
5. do `vagrant reload --provision`
6. Reboot your pc
7. Reinstall vagrant

For me reinstalling vagrant worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran across this before and the problem turned out to be related to my companies VPN.  If I tried running vagrant up connected to the VPN it would hang on mounting NFS, but if I disconnected from VPN and tried again it worked. Once running I could connect to VP  Probably goes back to it needing a stable internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to mount from guest to host (host being OSX?) trying mounting to a different path. You might be encountering issues with the space in Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant downloads binaries from its cloud while configuring a VM, so a stable internet connection is needed. In fact, an internet connection is necessary for using most of the Hashicorp products.

Comment: This issue is related to NFS mounting and has nothing to do with Vagrant downloading binaries from the cloud