# When "vagrant up" it says "It appears your machine doesn't support NFS" (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, vagrant, nfs

## Issue

when `vagrant up` it says "It appears your machine doesn't support NFS"

## Setups

- Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.6（15G1217）
- Vagrant 1.8.6
- Virtualbox 5.1.14 r112924 (Qt5.6.2)
- CentOS7

## Detail

I wanted to have synced_folder enabled with nfs, so added `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"` in Vagrantfile like in the [docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html) from vagrantup.com.

but every time I `vagrant up` it says like the below.

```
It appears your machine doesn't support NFS, or there is not an
adapter to enable NFS on this machine for Vagrant. Please verify
that `nfsd` is installed on your machine, and try again. If you're
on Windows, NFS isn't supported. If the problem persists, please
contact Vagrant support.
```

then I checked if nfsd is correctly working on the host, but it says it's enabled.

```
$ /sbin/nfsd status
nfsd service is enabled
nfsd is running (pid 212, 8 threads)
```

I reckon there seems to be some issues on the host, not on the guest, or I'm just missing the very basic things. But I couldn't find any hints to resolve this.

Please help with this issue if any suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Had the similar issue and for me reinstalling vagrant worked. [Here is the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56421709/7768504) of solutions I made from different resources which might solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by:

```
sudo apt-get install portmap nfs-kernel-server
```

Comment: Good question actually... I can remember that I posted this in hurry, just as a quick fix.. It would be good if someone has an actual explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your $PATH environment variables to see if you have **/sbin** on it. Generally this occurs because the system didn't find the nfsd command.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. yeah i have /sbin on my $PATH. but this was solved by installing `vagrant-vbguest`. It should work without it, I don't really have any idea about it, though.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when for some reason I have duplicate entries (for example, I have vagrant up 2 machines with the same config, same path and/or IP).

The solution for me was to:

1. edit the `/etc/exports` and remove the invalid entry
2. Restart NFS. In ubuntu it's like this: `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart`
3. Run now `vagrant up`